# Variable issues for loops with batch script

Tags: batch-file

Using the ported Linux command date, you can get the date from the current date minus X days. I am trying to loop 1-30 days which will generate dates, then use those dates in a findstr.  It seems that the loops work by themselves but when combined the inner for loop does not use the value X and date does not getr set. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong???!

```
    for /L %%x in (1,1,%SEARCHDAYS%) DO (
    set date1=
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('date.exe --date "Now -%%x days" +%%-m/%%-d/') do @set date1=%%a
    echo "%date1%"

    findstr /c:"%date1%" file.txt
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION, and then using "!" around the variables instead of "%"?

Comment: I get `c:\IBMITCSI300\programs\date.exe: invalid date `Now -!x! days'`

Comment: looking again I had disabledelayedexpansion, checking now'

Comment: Looks like that was the problem! Thanks!